# Adding Jekyll to Bootstrap template (on Github pages)

Tags: jekyll, bootstrap-5, github-pages

What do I need to add to a Bootstrap template, to get it working as a Jekyll site (e.g. on Github page)?

For instance, [Bare](https://github.com/startbootstrap/startbootstrap-bare/) ([preview](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/bare)) is a pretty bare-bones template.

I can upload this to Github pages that works fine, it works even faster if I add a `.nojekyll` file.

But instead, I want to make it easier to modify the content in simple markdown files (so no `.nojekyll`) and incorporate that content into the `index.html` using liquid tags.

What Jekyll elements are needed to make this work (`_config.yml` etc.)?

**Why?** A lot of awesome themes are available as freemium, free bootstrap, jekyll or hugo versions for a premium. I think the modifications are minimal, I'd like to be able to do this myself (where the license permits).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add boostrap to your layout, for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="{{ site.baseurl }}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <!-- ... -->
```

In your Bare example, it's done with SASS:

See these files:

- https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-bare/blob/9e17b3746e253e04eef809c9b5c8a303cb98ca13/src/scss/styles.scss#L3
- https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-bare/blob/9e17b3746e253e04eef809c9b5c8a303cb98ca13/src/pug/index.pug#L17